# sumifs function with multiple string in the cells evaluated

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question regarding sumifs function,

If I want to sum a column for exemple on time spend doing some sport, In column A I have "Sport.tennis", "Sport.swimming", "School.homework" and in column B I have "30", "20", "50".

Is it possible that the function sumifs, sum the time in colonne B if there is only "Sport" in column A ?

I've tried but it return 0, what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is located at [A1:B3] try this formula:

```
= SUMIF( A1:A3,"Sport.*",B1:B3)
```